List methods returns Iterable. Does it loses the order after applying a that methods?
I would like to keep the initial order while I apply different transformations to the items.
For example, I have a list that is ordered and I would like to apply a function using map to each element. This is my sample code:
List<int> numbers = [5,2,3,7];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a > b);
Iterable<int> numbersIncreased = numbers.map((e) => e + 3);

After the map, we get an Iterable. Does it keeps the order?
I would like to keep the initial order while I apply functions.

Yes, Iterables should iterate over the underlying collection in the same order.   For your specific case, a List is an Iterable, so iterating on a List will necessarily iterate over its elements in order.  The returned Iterable from List.map also must have the same order or else there will no longer be a correspondence between the original elements and the mapped results.

See List docs

Yes, it does keep the order.
And if you are unaware, you can simply call Iterable.toList() method to convert iterable back to List and see the order yourself.
final updatedList = numbersIncreased.toList();
print(updatedList);

Hope this helps :)
